# Why my default variable is not working in bash script?

Tags: bash

Here it is my script.

```
alias h='history "${1:-25}"'
```

My desirable result is when it gets variable like `h 100` it shows the results of `history 100` and no given inputs like `h`, it shows 25 elements like `history 25`.

But it works only when I hit `h` ,showing 25 results, other than that it gave me argument error.

```
-bash: history: too many arguments
```

I have tried `${1:-25}` but it returns error either.

```
-bash: $1: cannot assign in this way
```

Sorry if it is duplicated, but bash script  is quite tricky to look up since it has `$` and numbers.

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing this in your `.bashrc`?  Aliases don't take arguments.

Comment: @suvayu Yes that is true. That was the one I have misfigured. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alias can't accept parameters. They take arguments only at the end, and they are not positional (not accessible as `$1`, `$2`, etc).  It's equivalent to:

```bash
alias myAlias="command opt"
myAlias $@  
# Is the same as: command opt arg1 arg2 ...
```

---

You should use a bash function, one that will receive the param and call `history`:

```
function h() {
    x="${1:-25}"                       # Take arg $1, use 25 as fallback
    echo "Calling history with: $x"    # Log $x value as example
    history $x                         # Call history with $x
}
```

Usage:

```
~ $ h
Calling history with: 25
  448  xxx
  ...
  471  yyy
  472  zzz
~ $ h 1
Calling history with: 1
  473  h 1
~ $
```

Comment: It works just as I expected! Many thanks.